# Rule CLIPS to PROLOG

Tags: prolog, clips

What are the differences in creating the rules between CLIPS and PROLOG? 
If I have a CLIPS rule, as in the example, what would be its translation in PROLOG?

```
(defrule Rule1
(declare (salience 1))
?a<-(factf (classfact agg|sost|nonst|scon)(valore ?x)(idstruttura ?id)(pos ?n) )
?canc<-(fn (inter[ ?sin)(componenti $?comp)(genere ?gen)(numero ?num)(]inter ?des) )
(not (fn (inter[ ?sin)(]inter ?n)))
(test (= ?n (+ 1 ?des)))
=>
(retract ?canc)
(bind ?*idstruct* (+ 1 ?*idstruct*))
(printout t  crlf"********** Rule1 **********"crlf)
(assert (fn (inter[ ?sin)(componenti  $?comp ?id)(genere ?gen)(numero ?num)(]inter ?n)(idstruttura ?*idstruct*)))
)
```

Comment: I don't know or have never used CLIPS, but after a quick look the big difference between the two is that CLIPS uses forward-chaining while Prolog uses backward-chaining

Comment: @GuyCoder is right on the money, as usual. You clearly have a large library of CLIPS here that is not included in the question, but in general it is impossible to port directly between the two. In Prolog, you specify the goal and it figures out how to get there by working backwards, whereas in CLIPS, you set up some facts and basically say “go” and whatever triggers, triggers. Eventually you wind up with a steady state and other facts.

Comment: @DanielLyons There is at least a subset of CLIPS that could be translated into [Constraint Handling Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules), which is a forward-chaining inference engine in Prolog. Unlike CLIPS, CHR doesn't allow disjunctions in the head of a rule, so some of the `defrule`s would need to be re-written as multiple CHR rules.